# Missing "en-US" dictionary in portable installation of LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice-writer, spell-check, extension

I'm using the portable LibreOffice on a laptop where I don't have any admin rights.
Basically it works, except for dictionaries which have a somewhat inconsistent state display.

For example LibreOffice complains the hyphenation for "en-US" were not installed.

[image: Screenshot: Missing data for hyphenation (German)]

However a dictionary installed claims to support "en_US" (note the underscore instead of the minus), but the status of the dictionary is somewhat not correct:
I see some yellow triangle.

[image: Screenshot: Status of English dictionary (German)]

Maybe the reason is that I tried to install a newer version of the dictionary, but somehow that would not work.

[image: Screenshot: English dictionaries installed (German)]

When I try to update the existing dictionary, I get an error message:

[image: Screenshot: Updating English dictionary (German)]

[image: Screenshot: Error message when trying to update English dictionary (German)]

Unfortunately the error message "*an error occurred during file opening*" is no really helpful.

### Version Information

```text
Version: 7.5.7.1 (x86) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 47eb0cf7efbacdee9b19ae25d6752381ede23126
CPU threads: 8; OS: Windows 10.0 Build 19044; UI render: Skia/Raster; VCL: win
Locale: de-DE (de_DE); UI: de-DE
Calc: CL threaded
```